# How to set the ternary operator to get all textcontents + input values when looping through a table?

Tags: jquery, input, html-table

I got an editable table and want to loop through the table to get all entries. But the table has an option so you can add rows with input fields. To loop through the table I have the following code:

```
function t2array() {
    var erg = [];
    $("tr").each(function (index) {
        var row = {};
        var test = ($(this).children().find('input').length > 0) ?  (this).children().find('input') : $(this).children('td');
                    row['bla'] =  ($(this).children().find('input').length > 0) ? test[0].val : test[0].textContent;
                    row['blub'] = ($(this).children().find('input').length > 0) ? test[1].val : test[1].textContent;
                    ...etc...
                    erg.push(row);
    });
}
```

I know the selector for the value of the input is not correct but whatever I try I always get back "undefined" or "not a function" and I don't know how to solve that.

The table is pretty simple like:

```
<table>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" value="bla"></td>
            <td><input type="text" value="blub"></td>
            <td><input type="text" value="bling"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>bla2</td>
            <td>blub2</td>
            <td>bling3</td>
        </tr>
</table>
```

I can access the value of one input with:

```
var bla = $(this).children().find('input').val();
                console.log(blab);
```

but I tried anything to run it with the ternary operator and failed. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.val()` is a method of the jQuery object, it's not a property, also since you are using bracket notation, you should read `value` *property* of the element as it returns an HTMLInputElement object.

I would suggest using the `.map()` method:

```
function getVal($elem) {
   var $i = $elem.find('input');
   return $i.length ? $i.val() : $elem.text();
}

var vals = $('tr').map(function(){
    var $c = $('td', this);
    return {
        'bla': getVal($c.eq(0)), 
        'blub': getVal($c.eq(1)),
        'bling': getVal($c.eq(2))
    }
}).get();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/JaQLE/

Comment: Thx! To be honest i didnt try it yet. I found another solution that was easier and had a better usability than this. Now i just have a normal table and via double click the td transforms to a input. After clicking enter the new content is in the td and the input vanishs. So it's easier to loop through ;)